# Expired US Passports - what to do?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals

My parents and I are US citizens and we were planning to visit the Bahamas through the Balearia Ferry.

The problem is I just realized both my parents passports expired 11/2020 (I believe their passport cards might have also expired).

What can we do? This is by ferry only, we won't be doing air travel. Getting a new passport may take up to 2 months due to COVID.

Answer (score 4):

Balearia is very clear about this: you need a valid passport or passport card with a validity of 6 months after travel (see link below). [Balearia rules](https://www.baleariacaribbean.com/wps/portal/balcaribbean/balcaribbean/getready/beforetravelling/!ut/p/a1/lZHLboMwEEW_pQuWyGMexiyhiQjpgj5EU7yxDBhqCQyiTqrk60vSVZ-0sxvp3jtzZhBDT4hpcVCtMGrQojv3jHBCE4Kda7hJsnQFEYnzVUAeXfA8tEMMsUqb0TyjohSdFJMSfP8iuNQWtNLwSYr6aEEpm2GS3EziILtO6dYCCg7x6xDbVRiGtgeisUMRNDaREmPpYukTakE9VPteanNZiX-JOc8fK1Wj4i9xM1DxCxB4S7yf_BlJ17PATTduhB185yz5i9kf8DTZeDjOZoEzXyFKtzT3aQx-jtHDP4G2ix-KEcOnor59fX_WAv5HwTd8FwH8UBGgse-pe1S2KOmJ3K-v3gAs17Wa/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/) They also state

> *Note that Birth Certificates, Photo I. D, and naturalization documents ( Naturalization certificate) will no longer be accepted*

You will also need a negative Covid PCR test. Since many countries are currently heading into a new Covid spike, this is not a great time for travel anyway, so it may just be best to delay your trip until the new passports have been issued.

Answer (score 2):

> What can we do? ... Getting a new passport may take up to 2 months due to COVID.

You can pay a little extra for [an expedited application](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/get-fast.html).
If you live near a passport center, this can be relatively convenient.  Processing times do seem to be [longer than usual](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/processing-times.html), but the in-person service will get you your passports within three days.